# How to resolve `unresolved import 'XXX'` in a Visual Studio IronPython environment?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, ironpython, visual-studio-2019

I am developing IronPython scripts in Visual Studio 2019.

- The Python scripts work (i.e., they run without error).
- Visual Studio's autocomplete correctly offers options (`clr`, `sys`, `System`) when I type `import`*<space>*.

But when I type (or select) a choice on the list, it gets flagged (underlined in a squiggly green) with the error `Unresolved import 'XXX'` (where "XXX" is one of the choices on the autocomplete list). Within the editor, it is clear that the modules (namespaces) were not imported (i.e., no autocomplete on the imported modules).

What could be going on here? Autocomplete works, but Intellisense (or the analyzer) does not.

I have tried both 64- and 32-bit IronPython 2.7 environments. I have also tried typing the import statements into the interactive window without error. And, as I said above, the scripts work. I can run them and they work.

The code to reproduce is quite simple:

```py
import System
import clr
import sys
```

All 3 of those examples work with autocomplete. All 3 of those lines get flagged as unresolved and do not import within the editor.

Comment: Hi David, I tried to test it and have the green squiggly under the System/clr/sys, we can also report this issue to the IronPython in here: https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT So this is an IronPython issue rather than Visual Studio?

Comment: Hi David, you can also go to Help-Send Feedback-Report a problem to raise up this issue to the VS Product Team, waiting for the response from the product team engineers. If you want me to help you report, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks, @SaraLiu-MSFT. I reported it to both GitHub and Visual Studio

Comment: OK. That is an issue of Python. But is there a workaround?
I am trying to study IronPython by the book. 
Installed VS 2019 Community "IronPython" distribution. It should be inside. 
There is a Python 3.7 x64 environment active.
I can execute there "2+2" simple strings. But "import clr" does not work. Input autocomplete works in that place. That's weird.
Should VS2019 "IronPython" installer install IronPython, or CPython?